# DocuSign signing doesn't add a digital certificate for the signer

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign workflow where my company requires a valid Digital Signature and Digital Certificate for the Signer to be present in the completed document I receive from DocuSign. However, upon doing some test signatures, I see that DocuSign only applies the certificate to themselves and not to the signers. What am I missing?

[Certificate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKaIV.png)

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: How can a DocuSign Signer use a digital certificate?

Easy-peasy, DocuSign supports signing via all three types of electronic signatures:

- SES -- Simple Electronic Signatures (the usual technique)
- AES -- Advanced Electronic Signatures -- uses a digital certificate for the signer(s)
- QES -- Same as AES but the certificate chains up to a TSP (Trust Service Provider) that is chartered by a government.

If your use case requires AES or QES signatures, talk with your DocuSign representative and they'll take care of you. Some [docs](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Standards_Based_Signatures.pdf) and Google for [DocuSign Standards Based Signatures](https://www.google.com/search?q=docusign+standards+based+signatures).

Answer (score 1):

These applications use a digital certificate issued to their company. So the digital certificate used to sign the document has the function to guarantee the INTEGRITY of the document. (That the document cannot be modified since it was signed).
The other part for having a valid signed document is the identity of the signee. For this many platforms use alternative method such as biometric data, IPs, passwords or 2FA.

This has the advantage that you can send a document for signature and the signee doesn´t need a digital certificate. This is usually a problem because to obtain a personal certificate its costly and a personal process.

This method of signing is perfectly valid for most documents and most countries. At a legal level it stands as an equivalent of a handwritten signature. When the signee has a digital certificate issued to his name and uses it to sign it has the greatest value.

I´ve used software from firmar.online and have had no problems.They also have a webapp, SDKs and APIs.